# Beginner's stuff: How to stop CSS' Divs from overlapping?

Tags: css, html, overlap

First question ever, I started working on CSS about a month ago due to a job I got, but it seems I have encountered some problems I can't fix (mainly due to my inexperience and that it's someone else's CSS)

I won't beat around the bush so much and explain the problem before showing the code. There are a set of Div's in a form-like setting, but when the text get's too crowded it invades the next Div so, fixing it via CSS and not HTML, any fix on this? From the very problem I can imagine it's something so easy it's silly, but well, yeah.

Edit: I kinda of forgot to mention that part, I don't want them to be hidden, I want each div to automatically allow for the "previous" one to finish it's concent without overlapping (Tried with overflow: Auto but it gave them scrollbars, to all the forms in the whole site.

Here's a pic of how it looks at the moment, I'm sure you will see the problem right away

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBrLL.jpg

---

Here's the relevant HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="hue.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">

        <div class="column">
            <div class="form">
                <div class="form-nivel">
                    <label for="cfdiCreate:organizationRfc">RFC</label><label id="cfdiCreate:organizationRfc">XXXXXXXXXXXX</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-nivel">
                    <label for="cfdiCreate:organizationTaxSystem">Regimen    fiscal</label><label id="cfdiCreate:organizationTaxSystem">Sueldos y salarios</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-nivel">
                    <label for="cfdiCreate:organizationTaxAddress">Domicilio  fiscal</label><label id="cfdiCreate:organizationTaxAddress">XXXXXX Colonia Tecnológico  Monterrey,Nuevo León,México.C.P.XXXXXX</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-nivel">
                    <label for="cfdiCreate:organizationExpeditionPlace">Lugar de  expedición</label><label id="cfdiCreate:organizationExpeditionPlace">Suc.1 Chiapas,México.     </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column secondary">
            <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS

```
body {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    text-align: left;
}

.content {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    float: left;
    background: #;
    text-align: left;
}

    .content label, .content p {
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #024DA1;
        padding-left: 2%;
    }

.column {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    height: auto;
    background:;
}

.secondary {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form {
    display: block;
    width: 96%;
    height: auto;
    background:;
}

.form-nivel {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    width: 470px;
    min-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

    .form-nivel label {
        width: 160px;
        float: left;
        height: 20px;
        line-height: 20px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        text-align: right;
    }
```

Comment: What solution are you looking for? Do you want to hide the excess text? Do you want it to wrap? Are you expecting something else?

Comment: I kinda of forgot to mention that part, I don't want them to be hidden, I want each div to automatically allow for the "previous" one to finish it's concent without overlapping (Tried with overflow: Auto but it gave them scrollbars, to all the forms in the whole site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here. You are applying a CSS rule to all the labels. The overlapping happens because of this rule.

```
float: left;
```

To fix this, remove the .form-nivel label rule and add these.

```
.form-nivel label:nth-child(1) {
    width: 160px;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}

.form-nivel label:nth-child(2) {
    width: 160px;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: The reason for nth-childs is because I assume you are assembling this info as a column format. This will make sure that any further entries reflect this column/table like nature.

**I do recommend using tables in the future.

Comment: Your solution seems to be the one working best, and yes, I'm a newbie at this and on top of all, it isn't even my own code (they sent it to me to fix it...), so I'm having some problems, I will actually try doing it in a table as well.

For now the text seems to be formating itself after changing that, but the problem is in the third line, the second line of Address info starts at the very left of the screen, know any way to align it to where the first line started?

Comment: Try redoing it as a table. The table will help resolve the alignment issue. If not, let me know. Heres a link on basic tables in HTML. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Answer (score 2):

you can use overflow:hidden to hide the content if it overflows into the next one

Comment: I kinda of forgot to mention that part, I don't want them to be hidden, I want each div to automatically allow for the "previous" one to finish it's concent without overlapping (Tried with overflow: Auto but it gave them scrollbars, to all the forms in the whole site.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS logic for the left labels and the right labels are the same.

First thing you should do is set them apart.

```
<div class="form-nivel">
    <label class="leftLabel" for="cfdiCreate:organizationRfc">RFC</label>
    <label class="rightLabel" id="cfdiCreate:organizationRfc">XXXXXXXXXXXX</label>
</div>
```

- Notice the added class

Then on your css you would do something like this:

```
.form-nivel label.leftLabel {
    width: 160px;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}

.form-nivel label.rightLabel {
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

I made the right labels bigger and aligned them to the left.

Also, you should add:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

on the html head. This is to be able to display characters with accents.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Right now I'm trying this method as well, but doesn't seem to have made much difference after dividing them in left and right labels (a problem on my end, I'm sure), and yes, just added that meta charset, worked wonders!

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply keep your `<label/>`s inline? Removing all the unneccessary declarations...

```
.form-nivel label {
    margin-right: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

between each row.

```
<div class="form-nivel">
    <label for="cfdiCreate:organizationRfc">RFC</label>
    <label        id="cfdiCreate:organizationRfc">XXXXXXXXXXXX</label>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="form-nivel">
    <label for="cfdiCreate:organizationTaxSystem">Regimen    fiscal</label>
    <label id="cfdiCreate:organizationTaxSystem">Sueldos y salarios</label>
</div>
```